# Install gnome desktop in kubuntu

Tags: 12.04, gnome, apt, kubuntu

I am trying to install gnome desktop from kubuntu. So I did this : `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` It ran well but now I am getting this error:

```
sudeep@sudeep:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 firefox-globalmenu : Depends: firefox (= 20.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
 firefox-gnome-support : Depends: firefox but it is not going to be installed
 lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure : Depends: firefox but it is not going to be installed
 xul-ext-websites-integration : Depends: firefox (>= 9.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please help me correct this.

**EDIT**
sudo apt-get -f install ubuntu-desktop

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 firefox-globalmenu : Depends: firefox (= 20.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
 firefox-gnome-support : Depends: firefox but it is not going to be installed
 lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure : Depends: firefox but it is not going to be installed
 xul-ext-websites-integration : Depends: firefox (>= 9.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: "You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these" <=== Did you already try that? With no packages.

Answer (score 1):

Try type then

sudo apt-get -f install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Please look at the edit.